# Why does jline's TerminalBuilder not accept function call?

Tags: java, console-application, jline

Please dont ban me for this question, i am a noob and i have googled this for hours now.

To make a console based Snake Game, i plan to use the jline Libary.
However, when i try to call "Terminal" 's function getHeight()(i imported org.jline.Terminal already), there is an error:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method **getHeight()** from the type **Terminal**

this happens even though the Terminal import does have a function called getHeight().

i have an assumption: i think i need to generate an instance of something to use it. but for what do i need to generate an instance.
or is the assumption wrong?

Do you have an Idea how to solve this?

Kind regards,

your Alwin :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[`org.jline terminal.Terminal#getHeight()`](https://github.com/jline/jline3/blob/jline-parent-3.21.0/terminal/src/main/java/org/jline/terminal/Terminal.java#L200-L202) is not a `static` method and therefore needs to be called on an instance of `org.jline terminal.Terminal`.
You should probably use [`org.jline terminal.TerminalBuilder`](https://github.com/jline/jline3/blob/jline-parent-3.21.0/terminal/src/main/java/org/jline/terminal/TerminalBuilder.java#L37-L40) to obtain one.

The import merely allows you to use `Terminal` without the package name.